# More aesthetic norms, absolute values, parentheses, etc

Tags: brackets, fractions, delimiters

This is nothing too important, and I've decided to make all three questions into one because they are more or less related. Sometimes when I type math equations, I find them not as beautiful as I thought they would be, and most of the time it's because of symbols like `()` or `\| \|` of various sizes. Below are some examples:

1. When writing an exponent with parentheses inside a pair of parentheses, the most convenient way is to write `f(x^{(n_1)})`.
2. When writing a norm in which there are fractions and non-fractions, I'm using something like this: `\left\| x - \frac{x}{\|x\|} \right\|`.
3. An operator acting on some kind of fraction: `T\left(\frac{y}/{\|y\|}\right)`.

The problems are (maybe it's just me b/c this is really a subjective issue):

1. For the exponent, it's just so unsatisfying to see that the `)` outside is shorter and also wider than the one inside. I was able to roughly achieve what I want by using `f \scalebox{1}[1.2]{(}x^{(n_1)}\scalebox{1}[1.2]{)}`, but clearly doing so is *much* more time consuming.
2. This one makes me feel like the norm symbols are too large, and the first part (equivalent to `\Bigg\| x` looks especially weird. However, replacing them with `\Big\|` gives me something not large enough to cover the fractions inside.
3. This is just... weird -- the letter `T` is so small compared with the `\left(`, in this case `\Bigg(`, and it looks a little bit disproportionate. Again, switching to `\bigg( \bigg)` gives me a pair of parenthesis that is not big enough to cover the fraction inside.
4. In text math fractions: with simply things I would do `a / b`, but when the fraction is more complicated, I either have to use `\frac{}{}` or `\dfrac{}{}`. With a complited fraction, the former is too small, whereas the second one sometimes look too big.

Maybe I was just being very weird, but I appreciate it if anyone can share any suggestion on how to make symbols like these more aesthetic (or maybe some methods, e.g., in preamble, to change the size of `\big`, `\bigg` ,and `\dfrac`?).

Comment: Many of the problems you raise go away by themselves if one stops using `\left` and `\right` excessively. Is the `/` ("slash") symbol in `T\left(\frac{y}/{\|y\|}\right)` intended?